# simulate sinusodial graphs in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation

My today's question is how to simulate continuously some graph in matlab? For example: let us consider the following simplest code

```
x = 0 : 0.1 : 10;
z = sin(x);
plot(x,z), grid
```

When I run this code, I get  usually *sin* function graph, whose figure is  given below
[image]

Actually, what I need is, that the graph is static, i.e. that it does not move. What I want  is that simulate this graph, namely  appears  on  window, disappears and  then again repeat this procedure, as I guess I need loop for this, but maybe there is some  built-in function for simulation graphs in matlab? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to animate this graph? MATLAB offers [numerous ways](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation.html) to do that.

One of the simplest would be generating a short movie frame-by-frame using [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) and then playing it with the [`movie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) command. For example:

```
%// Generate movie
x = 0:0.1:10;
FRAMES = 32;                  %// Total number of frames
for k = 1:FRAMES
    ph = k * 2 * pi / FRAMES; %// Accumulate phase
    plot(x, sin(x + ph))      %// Generate plot
    grid, axis equal
    M(k) = getframe;          %// Capture frame
end

%// Play movie 10 times
movie(M, 10)
```